# INDEX rebuild and reorganize based on fragmentation results in SQL Server 2012

Tags: sql, sql-server-2012

I know there are some scripts to detect index fragmentation, and based on the results, REBUILD or REORGANIZE. I have tried with some for SQL Server 2005 without results.
Could you help advise?

Comment: Just [get Ola's stuff](https://ola.hallengren.com/).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check out the script provided on TechNet: https://gallery.technet.microsoft.com/scriptcenter/Check-SQL-Server-a-a5758043 that illustrates how to check for fragmented indexes.

```
SELECT 
    OBJECT_NAME(ind.OBJECT_ID) AS TableName,
    ind.name AS IndexName, 
    indexstats.index_type_desc AS IndexType,
    indexstats.avg_fragmentation_in_percent
FROM sys.dm_db_index_physical_stats(DB_ID(), NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL) indexstats
INNER JOIN sys.indexes ind 
    ON ind.object_id = indexstats.object_id
    AND ind.index_id = indexstats.index_id
WHERE indexstats.avg_fragmentation_in_percent > 30
ORDER BY indexstats.avg_fragmentation_in_percent DESC
```

Change the percent from 30 to whatever you are comfortable with. I tend to tolerate up to 30% fragmentation as a starting point. For fragmentation higher than that, I prefer rebuilding more than reorganizing. You can check out Kendra Little/Brent Ozar's blog about rebuild vs. reorg http://www.brentozar.com/archive/2013/09/index-maintenance-sql-server-rebuild-reorganize/